# Extracting a randomly-chosen string within a main string: MATLAB

Tags: regex, string, matlab, random, cell

The strings that I am working with are similar to the one written below:

`String_1='{2,2,1,1,{1,1,2,2,{1,2,{1,1,1,1,1}},2,2},{1,2,{1,2,2,2,2,2},2},{1,1},2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1}';`

First, I must randomly select one of the numbers within the string. Afterward, I have to **extract** the strings from the selected number to the first `}` and create **another** string with it (see Figure **A**). Notice, we only move from **left** to the **right** side.

[image: Example A]

**However**, if there are `n` ***opening*** brackets within the selected number, we must skip `n` ***closing*** bracket to get to the closing bracket that we are looking for as shown in Figure **B**.

[image: Example B]
[image]

> Please let me know if you have any comment or suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the position of `1` and `2` to get a random position.

```
inds = find(String_1 == '1' | String_1 == '2');
random_number_pos = inds(randi(length(inds)));
```

Now, we can use the concept of stack to find the first `}` which is not opened.

```
parentheses_opened = 0;
start_ind = random_number_pos + 2; end_ind = 0;
for ind = (random_number_pos + 2):length(String_1)
    if(String_1(ind) == '}' && parentheses_opened == 0)
        end_ind = ind - 1;
        break;
    elseif(String_1(ind) == '{')
        parentheses_opened = parentheses_opened + 1;
    elseif(String_1(ind) == '}')
        parentheses_opened = parentheses_opened - 1;
    end
end

String_2 = String_1(start_ind:end_ind);
String_1((start_ind - 1):(end_ind + 1)) = [];
```